# How to extract collections in Mongo using Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Please apologize me if my question is naive, I am new to python and I am trying my hand on using the collections using pymongo. I have tried to extract the names using

```
collects = db.collection_names(); #This returns a list with names of collections
```

But when I tried to get the cursor using

```
cursor = db.collects[1].find(); #This returns a cursor which has no reference to a collection.
```

I understand that the above code uses a string instead of an object. So, I was wondering how I could accomplish this task of retaining a cursor for each collection in the DB, which I can use later to perform operations of search and update etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the pymongo driver you must use the [`get_collection`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.get_collection) method or a dict-style lookups instead. Also you may want to set the `include_system_collections` to `False` in [`collection_names`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.collection_names) so you don't  include system collections (e.g system.indexes)

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.db
collects = db.collection_names(include_system_collections=False)
cursor = db.get_collection(collects[1]).find()
```

or

```
cursor = db[collects[1]].find()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sry, i can't create a comment yet, but have you tried?:

```
cursor = db.getCollection(collects[1]).find();
```

Comment: If @Friwi's answer was satisfactory it is customary to accept the answer.  One because the answer helped you, second so that other users know that this question has been resolved.